# Rotated stroke doesn't fill the height

Tags: android

I am designing UI of an application and want to separate my layout to 4 parts. (Using two orthogonal lines).

Layout background must be `sweep` type gradiant color like below:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/gradiant_center_color"
        android:endColor="@color/gradiant_end_color"
        android:startColor="@color/gradiant_start_color"
        android:type="sweep" />
</shape>
```

To create orthogonal lines, I am using from `rotate` and `stroke` as follow:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item>
       <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="90"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%" >
           <shape android:shape="line" >
               <stroke
                   android:width="1dip"
                   android:color="@color/separator_color" />
           </shape>
       </rotate>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape
           android:shape="line" >
           <stroke
               android:width="1dp"
               android:color="@color/separator_color" />
       </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now, I combine two drawables and create background like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="@color/gradiant_center_color"
                android:endColor="@color/gradiant_end_color"
                android:startColor="@color/gradiant_start_color"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/separator_border"/>
</layer-list>
```

All right, after setting layout background, my background is :

[image]

As you see on the image, horizontal line doesn't fill the screen. So why ?! 
Please give me a solution to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A line shape draws a horizontal line the length of the drawables width, which is then being rotated 90 degrees (the 2 lines are the same length).

You might be able to put `<size width="999999dp" height="1dp" />` inside the rotated `<shape>`

Or,

put a `<scale>` either wrapping the `<rotate>` or inside it (wrapping the `<shape>`)

```
<rotate ...>
    <scale scaleWidth="200%" scaleHeight="100%">
        <shape ...>
```

or

```
<scale scaleWidth="200%" scaleHeight="100%">
    <rotate ...>
        <shape ...>
```

Comment: Added another suggestion

Comment: could you please explain more ?